# MergeSort Error

Tags: python, mergesort, nonetype

My code for Merge Sort is below. When I run it on the test array [5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 4, 9, 11], I get the error: "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()", which gets thrown at the beginning of the merge method. My print outs are as follows:
 - trying to merge left:  [5]
 - trying to merge right:  [3]
 - merged array:  [3, 5]
 - trying to merge left:  [2]
 - trying to merge right:  [1]
 - merged array:  [1, 2]
 - trying to merge left:  None
 - trying to merge right:  None

It appears I have successfully merged the first 4 elements, and then it attempts to merge two null elements, and I cannot figure out why that happens in the first place.

```
def mergeSort(array, size):
    # BASE CASE
    if size <= 1:
        return array

    #split in half recursively and once they're all one element, merge
    else:
        left = mergeSort(array[:size / 2], size / 2)
        right = mergeSort(array[size / 2:], size / 2)

        temp = merge(left, right)
        print "merged array: ", temp

def merge(leftElements, rightElements):
    print("trying to merge left: "), leftElements
    print("trying to merge right: "), rightElements
    lengthLeft = len(leftElements)
    lengthRight = len(rightElements)
    mergedArray = []

    # - i is the index for leftElements
    # - j is the index for rightElements

    i = 0
    j = 0
    while (i < lengthLeft):
        while (j < lengthRight):
            if leftElements[i] < rightElements[j]:
                mergedArray.append(leftElements[i])
                i += 1
            elif leftElements[i] > rightElements[j]:
                mergedArray.append(rightElements[j])
                j += 1
            else:
                mergedArray.append(leftElements[i])
                mergedArray.append(rightElements[j])
                i += 1
                j += 1

            booleanLeft = i >= lengthLeft
            booleanRight = j >= lengthRight

            if ((i >= lengthLeft) or (j >= lengthRight)):
                break
        if ((i >= lengthLeft) or (j >= lengthRight)):
            break

    # now need to account for the case when one array clears before the other
    if (i < lengthLeft):
        for q in range(i, lengthLeft):
            mergedArray.append(leftElements[q])
    if (j < lengthRight):
        for q in range(j, lengthRight):
            mergedArray.append(rightElements[q])
    return mergedArray

print(mergeSort([5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 4, 9, 11], 8))
```

Comment: Did you walk through this with a debugger and look at what's happening at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Your mergeSort function does not return anything

Therefore by definition it returns now, which is where the nones, are coming from.

Just add a return and you should be fine.